# In Rancher, K8 cluster failing with "failed to communicate with API server during namespace check: context deadline exceeded"

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, kubernetes, rancher

Currently, a simple angular application is running in a docker container in kubernetes.

The error reads: `"Cluster health check failed: Failed to communicate with API server during namespace check: Get "https://3.227.22.31:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system?timeout=45s": context deadline exceeded"`

Rancher also won't allow viewing the cluster itself; the link to it is greyed out and disabled under the Explore Cluster section.

There seems to be disk pressure issues as well. I read that this could be caused by logging but unsure.